# Is it possible to define a linear transformation piecewise as different functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to proof that it is not possible. I suspect that if a linear transformation  $T:\mathbb{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}$ can be defined such that:
$$
T(v)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
F(v) & v\in A\\ 
G(v) & v\in B
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
With:
$$
F,G:\mathbb{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}
$$
Then $\forall v\in \mathbb{V}, \ F(v)=G(v)$
That would mean that a linear transformation can't be defined piecewise, in a non trivial manner.
As a reminder, a linear transformation can be defined as a function between vector spaces such that:
$$
T(\alpha\cdot u+\beta\cdot v)=\alpha\cdot T(u)+\beta\cdot T(v)\\
\forall \alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{K} \ and \ \forall u,v\in \mathbb{V}
$$

Advance:
In the case that F or G are linear it is easily proved.
Let be $u\in A$ and $v\in B$, and suppose that $u+v\in A$ (it'll be the same if it's in B). If $F$ is linear, it follows that:
$$T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)\\
 =F(u)+G(v)
$$
and
$$
T(u+v)=F(u+v)
$$
then
$$
F(u+v)-F(u)=F(v)
$$
and
$$
F(u+v)-F(u)=T(u+v)-F(u)\\
T(u+v)-F(u)=(F(u)+G(v))-F(u)=G(v)
$$
So
$$F(v)=G(v)$$
As you can note, that is a very small case since I'm using that one of the functions is linear. I think it should be true for every pair of functions. I suppose the proof would use the fact that a linear transformation can be defined by the image of a basis.
If $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{V}$, then every $v\in \mathbb{V}$ can be written as $v=\sum \alpha_i e_i$. And if T is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{V}$, then $T(v)=\sum \alpha_i T(e_i)$

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be?

Comment: Thank you for defining Linear Transformation.  That is awesome (+1).

Comment: @Joaquin A and B are sets, maybe worth consider them as $A\cup B=\mathbb{V}$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible.  The point is that the values of $F$ on $B$ and of $G$ on $A$ don't affect $T$, and could be anything.
For example, suppose $\mathbb V = \mathbb W = \mathbb R$ and $T(x) = x$.  You could take $A = [0,\infty)$, $B = (-\infty,0)$ with
$F(x) = |x|$ and $G(x) = -|x|$.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I can see now that i started the problem wrong, but your response is very useful. My original problem is that a student was supposed to apply a linear transformation to a non trivial subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, **working graphically**, and this subset was composed of simple sets with geometric shapes. The student chose to apply different linear transformations to each geometric shape and was arguing that the whole transformation was linear.

Comment: As @Robert wrote, the important thing is that $F$ and $G$ don't interfere with the linearity of $T$, so uniting linear pieces of non linear functions in a way that the pieces generate _the same_ linearity (linearity that don't affect $T$) creates a valid linear transformation.